# C++ Timed function that calls itself

Tags: visual-c++

I want to create a class that will help me call function but the function will call itself until condition is reached and inside condition block will be timed call, and it will be using Lambda, let me show you example (it doesnt contain lambda)

```
void RecursiveFunction()
{
    static DWORD tempBlockTimer = 0; // timer
    const unsigned int time_ms = 200; // delay for timer

    
    static const int maxCalls = 14220;
    static int currentCallCount = 0;


    if ( currentCallCount < maxCalls ) // condition
    {
        tempBlockTimer = GetTickCount();

        if ( GetTickCount() - tempBlockTimer >= time_ms ) // timer check
        {
            currentCallCount++; // count this call

            /*
            Do something
            */
        }
        RecursiveFunction(); // call function itself until condition is reached
    }
}
```

what I want to achieve is to easily call InterestingFunc() just once and this function will call SomeFunc() until some condition is reached

Comment: `GetTickCount() - tempBlockTimer` will almost always be 0, or at most 1, since you assigned `tempBlockTimer = GetTickCount()` just before. The function you show will die very quickly with stack overflow.

Comment: What's `InterestingFunc` and `SomeFunc` and how, if at all, are they related to `RecursiveFunction`. Your *"what I want to achieve"* explanation doesn't appear to have anything to do with the code shown.

Comment: Why not just run a loop that performs the action, then [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep)s for a while, then repeats? Recursion makes no sense here.